# PHP upgrade issues

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am running a MacBook Air with macOS Sierra 10.12.3. I upgraded my PHP from 5.x to 7.1.1 according to [this site](https://php-osx.liip.ch/) and now I am having two issues:

a) The PHP process startup takes around 7 seconds, even for a `php -v` to print PHP's version. edit: Solved.

b) Apache does not serve my pages anymore locally. Chrome just shows the generic error page with "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I have restarted the apache service but don't really know what else to do. The apache vhosts config file worked before and still looks good. edit: Also nothing in the apache error logs.

edit: The syslog shows

`(org.apache.httpd[71685]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0]
(org.apache.httpd): Service only ran for 5 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 5 seconds`

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Look at your apache error logs, there might be a clue there.

Comment: @aynber Thank you, I forgot to mention, there are no entries following the apache restart

Comment: This error might be a DNS or IP error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, try to remove everything in Chrome and start again.

Comment: @Soheyl Same error in Firefox and Safari. Pinging that URL in the console shows 127.0.0.1.

Comment: anything in other logs, syslog or so?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thank you, it indeed shows something, I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://php-osx.liip.ch is a pretty good site, I used to use it before to upgrade my `php` installations. I found that time to time it would be untrust worthy and sometimes brick my installation. **Edit** The scripts used on that site usually compile PHP when ran and this can lead to some interesting quirks and inconsistencies. So I switched to using `brew`.

[Brew](https://brew.sh) is a handy tool for Mac that works a lot like `apt-get` or `yum`. I would recommend you try this, it adds libraries in a way that allow you to purge them from your machine and reverting to older versions.

```
$ brew search php71
# lists all the matches for php71, you will find "homebrew/php/php71"

$ brew install homebrew/php/php71
# installs php71, it will give you some good instructions if there are errors
# typically some permission errors, but it gives commands to run too

$ brew link homebrew/php/php71
# overrides the local php command with "homebrew/php/php71"

$ php -v
PHP 7.1.1 (cli) ...
```

Then I would suggest looking at [PHP Local Server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) that is built in if its still not working. Although I am 99% sure your issues will be resolved.

In future upgrading your php version is as simple as doing the above again where `php71` is your new version (example `php72` for `7.2`). Removing your old version is easy, although does no harm and does allow you to quickly switch your versions around with a single command line option.

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the issue of php taking 7 seconds to start, but unfortunately the apache service keeps crashing.

Comment: The command line webserver does not handle the virtual host rewrites unfortunately and is thus not an option but works fine otherwise

Comment: Hmm, have you restarted the `httpd` service? `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

Comment: Many times, but it I solved it now, please see my answer.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it solved the (a) issue, put me on the right path and I am glad that you chimed in!

Answer (score 2):

Solved it now.

The issue with Apache was that an additional config file in `/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf` was created that loaded the php7.1 module, but the module loading of php5 in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` was not disabled.

Loading both obviously crashed apache and commenting out the `LoadModule` in `httpd.conf` solved it. I have no idea why the installation routine didn't do that though.

Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: I was just about to link the page that mentioned this, but good to see its fixed.

Comment: Oh man.... i've spent so many hours trying to fix this. thanks i love you!

Comment: OSX update has made such a mess of all the conf files, there are .conf.previous files all over the place. This is crazy

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. I just couldn't figure out why php5 was still being loaded!